# Can I access parent document properties in has_child script filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to compare a child property to a parent property in my elasticsearch query. Essentially I want all parents who don't have any children with certain properties. Like this (but this doesn't work):

```
query: {
  filtered: {
    filter: {
      bool: {
        must_not: [
          {
            has_child: {
              type: 'child_type',
              query: {
                filtered: {
                  query: {
                    match_all: {}
                  },
                  filter: {
                    bool: {
                      must: [
                        {
                          script: {
                            script: "doc['field1'].value < parent['parent_field1'].value"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    query: {
      match_all: {}
    }
  }
}
```

I can access doc['_parent'] but that is just the ID of the parent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. It would be prohibitively expensive to access another document (the parent) from within the context of the child. I solved my problem using two separate queries.

Comment: Is this still true as of the newer versions?

Comment: @cava23 can you share how you archive that  becoz I have same issue.